# Make flow between WSO2 EBS to WSO2 Appserver

Tags: wso2

I successfully installed WSO2 EBS and WSO2 Application server in same machine and also i resolved the port conflict issue. I installed backend services in app server mentioned in wso2 portal. My question is how to create a sequence between ebs to appserver in ebs sequence option for message flow between ebs - appserver - ebs.

note: Refer 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining.

If it is not possible the above condition means please tell how to make a message flow between ebs to app server mentioned in above URL.

Could you please send any document, video, screen shot regarding this issue as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this service chaining scenario (in the link you mentioned) what happens is that the services are hosted in Application Server (AS). This hosted URL of the service is then defined as an endpoint in ESB. So when the proxy service in ESB receives a request, mediation is performed on the message and then sent to the endpoint that is defined in the send mediator. The response received from this endpoint, is then through the ESB to the consumer.

If you are looking at how to implement a service chaining scenario, this document will provide more detailed information.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/11/enterprise-service-integration-wso2-esb

Hope this helps.....

Answer (score 0):

In this example I had a proxy service that receives an incoming message from a client.
With this incoming message I extract the information I need from it, in this case the offset and limit using the property mediator as you can see in this line:

```
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" name="offset" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:offset"/>
```

I use the log mediator in this sequence because I need to see the values stored in the properties to debug stuff.

After that I create a new message using the payloadFactory because I need to send this message to the Application Server with that format.

```
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <p:listar_persona_paginado xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">            
            <p:offset>$1</p:offset>            
            <p:limit>$2</p:limit>         
         </p:listar_persona_paginado>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:offset"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:limit"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
```

Then I send the created message to an endpoint in the Application Server using the send mediator:

```
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9765/services/buscarPersona"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
```

All the pieces together:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <log>
      <property name="SECUENCIA" value="ENTRADA DEL LISTADO DE PERSONAS"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" name="offset" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:offset"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" name="limit" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:limit"/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <p:listar_persona_paginado xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">            
            <p:offset>$1</p:offset>            
            <p:limit>$2</p:limit>         
         </p:listar_persona_paginado>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:offset"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://ejemplos.cuba.cu/Persona" expression="//p:listarPersonas/p:limit"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9765/services/buscarPersona"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own sequences within the ESB as much as you need. But when you access these sequences from a client, you need to implement a proxy service within the ESB. That proxy service allows you to call any number of sequences within that proxy service. In your case you need to access the backend services which are located in WSO2 application server. You can access these services from  mediator. For a list of examples, please refer the below link

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Proxy+Service+Samples